# Using Scrapy with Javascript and iFrames and alternatives

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy to scrape the U.S. government regulations website (www.regulations.gov).  It's got a ton of information on it, but it's a terrible website, that is chock-full of javascript and iframes.  I tried to run some simple Scrapy spiders, but I can't parse anything out because everything loads through Javascript and iframes.

For instance, on the [main search page](http://www.regulations.gov/#!searchResults;rpp=10;so=ASC;sb=agency;po=0), this block of code actually loads the results table:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Regs/Regs.nocache.js?REGS211-b3"></script>

<title>Regulations.gov</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
</head>

<body class="bodyLoading">
<!-- this is required for GWT history support -->
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
<!-- For printing window contents  -->
<iframe id="__printingFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0;" ></iframe>
```

And, individual results pages have the same problem.  For instance, [this page](http://www.regulations.gov/#!documentDetail;D=ACF-2010-0003-0055) has the same source as above.

Can Scrapy handle this problem at all?  Are there any alternatives that might be able to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatives :
try

1) [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

2) [imacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/)

3) [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)